# Pythonic way of repeating until a return value is not None

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of URLs, where some of the URLs might be invalid. I want to gather an image from one randomly chosen URL. The `get_image_from_url` function returns `None` if the URL or the image is invalid. Therefore, I want to repeat the line `get_image_from_url(random.choice(urls))` until it does not return `None`. Because `urls` might be a large list I do not want to filter out invalid urls for the complete list before. I did the following:

```
image = None
while not image:
    image = ImageNetUtilities.get_image_from_url(random.choice(urls))

return image
```

I wonder if there is any better (more pythonic) way of achieving my goal. I'm using Python3.

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments I should remove any url I already selected. I replaced

```
image = ImageNetUtilities.get_image_from_url(random.choice(urls))
```

with

```
image = ImageNetUtilities.get_image_from_url(urls.pop(random.randrange(len(urls))))
```

Comment: You probably could use a `thread` to load the assets.

Comment: What is "unpythonic" about your code?

Comment: I would like to have the while loop including the return within one line of code (if possible)

Comment: You should remove the urls that you choose, so the random does not pick them again. If you want to re use your list do not forget to copy the list before removing stuff. Also consider all urls could give None, otherwise it will be stuck forever.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I updated my question. From the list of urls at least one is valid so I don't need to consider that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A version that 1) avoids an endless loop if *all* URLs are invalid, 2) tests each URL only once and 3) uses cool Python features would be:

```
image = next(filter(None, map(ImageNetUtilities.get_image_from_url, random.sample(urls, k=len(urls)))))
```

Instead of `random.sample(urls, k=len(urls))` you could also `random.shuffle` your list beforehand.

To pick this apart:

- [`random.sample(urls, k=len(urls))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) produces a randomly shuffled version of your list
- [`map(ImageNetUtilities.get_image_from_url, ...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) produces a generator which successively applies `ImageNetUtilities.get_image_from_url` to each URL
- [`filter(None, ...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) removes all `None` values from the `map` generator
- [`next(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) iterates this generator and returns the first value, or raises a `StopIteration` exception if no URLs are valid